# Correctly Setting Transform Origin to Enable Zoom to Mouse Point in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, electron, transform

I'm writing an application using electron and interact.js , for image and video reference, it would best seem like the app pureRef (I decided to make that app since pureRef won't add gifs and video format capabilities), so when you start it, you get a drop zone to drop files into(images and or videos) which are handled by their format and set as divs with a classname .draggable, on initial their position is relative in order for them to be organized on dropping them, but after trying to move or resize one of them they become absolute and I calculate their position before changing their position, in order to translate them into place.

all of them are being contained under a div that is created as well with the id 'grid-snap'
and grid-snap parent is body, that way I manage to center the container to the center of the page and the container background color is different from the body background color.

when you try dragging or resizing the .draggable elements(the images and vids that you dropped), the container width and height are increasing accordingly

that way you get the effect you increase the 'canvas' size that you can drag elements to(which is true)

but, right now I'm trying to add a feature to pan and zoom to mouse curser point, and I found something that works using transform-origin, but then when trying to zoom from one point to another point, the transform-origin changes but it's not changes in according to my mouse curser point, the idea is to keep using transform-origin to the point on the screen that my mouse pointer is.

here's the code I wrote

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', (event)=> {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('the point of the mouse before is - '+ event.clientX + ', ' + event.clientY);
    //lastZoomPoint = {left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY};
    var cont = document.getElementById('grid-snap')
    const lastPositions = savePositions();
    const mouseX = event.clientX - cont.offsetLeft;
    const mouseY = event.clientY - cont.offsetTop;

    // Calculate the new scale
    if (event.deltaY < 0) {
      // Zoom in
      scale *= 1.24;
    } else {
      // Zoom out
      scale /= 1.24;
    }

    cont.style.transformOrigin = `${mouseX}px ${mouseY}px`;
    cont.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
});
```

And here's my css

```
.draggable {
    position: relative;
    /* resize: both; */
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}


#drop_zone {
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    width: fit-content;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    /* margin: 50vh 50vw 50vh 50vw; */
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
body {
    /* width: -webkit-fill-available;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 10%;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; */
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* margin: 10%; */
}
html {
    background-color: #202020;
    width: -webkit-fill-available;   /* viewport width */
    height: -webkit-fill-available;  /* viewport height */
    overflow: hidden;
}
html, body {
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
/* html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px; 
} */
.textbox {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px;
  }
textarea {
    background-color: rgb(48 48 48 / 50%);
    color: #ebebeb;
    font-family: Roboto;
    border: 2px solid #242222;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-size: 32px;
    outline-color: #3d3f48;
}
.close-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #grid-snap {
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* padding: 2%; */
    /* margin: 1rem 0 0 1rem; */
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    touch-action: none;
    transition: width 0.05s ease, height 0.05s ease;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
```

I didn't know if to add any more code but here's my github for it
https://github.com/turhtkar/betterRef-app

I can also try and provide more information, just ask me, but if you think you might be able to figure that one out, it will help a lot, the issue seems simple, but for some reason it's not

I've tried tracking the data, the actual transform origin and what it should be relative to the point of my mouse.
and I've tried different approaches, also tried using transition translate with scale, but I couldn't figure out how I can do it right.